# Spring Cloud Zuul Monitor/CircuitBreaker All Routes via Hystrix

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, netflix-zuul

I am using Spring Cloud and @EnableZuulProxy Is it possible to monitor all routes configured in application.yml using hystrix via /hystrix.stream? In the example below I would like to have a simple way to monitor all request made to the down stream product service.  I understand that I can do this on the product service itself, but is it possible to monitor Zuul request.  This would be useful for any down stream services that are not owned (third party) and cannot be annotated with the @HystrixCommand.

`zuul:
   routes:
    item:
      serviceId: product
      path: /product/**`

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is yes. Add `spring-cloud-starter-hystrix` and add `@EnableCircuitBreaker` to your main class. That will enable `/hystrix.stream`. Zuul uses hystrix when forwarding to other services.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, when doing this, i'm getting back empty data, the /hystrix.stream returns ping: even when I generate traffic to the /product path, in fact any URL that begins with http://localhost:8080/hystrix.stream/someurlthatdoesnexit returns the same.

Comment: so @spencergibb any feedback? or what is the not simple answer?  Im happy to read though the docs if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for **Zuul uses hystrix when forwarding to other services**. I had doubt on this. Since I am using `@EnableHystrix` annotation so `@EnableCircuitBreaker` is default meta annotation which comes by default.

Comment: I think `@EnableCircuitBreaker` is already on the `@EnableZuulProxy`. But there is no circuit unless you are using ribbon (service ids not hard-coded URLs). Anyway the code you posted above will generate a /hystrix.stream. if it's empty then it hasn't handled any requests yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and changing `@EnableCircuitBreaker` to `@EnableHystrix` fixed the problem.

With `@EnableHystrix` I can see all the routed calls on the Hystrix dashboard.

**Update**

See comment below, this is indeed not the fix.

Comment: I don't think that was the fix. Probably you just needed some traffic in your endpoints.

Comment: @DaveSyer yes you are right. I reverted to the old notation and it's still working. I had traffic before so it was something else that triggered it. Could it be adding ribbon properties to my route?

Comment: If you weren't using ribbon you wouldn't get a metrics stream, so maybe. It depends what you did.

Comment: @DaveSyer I thought Ribbon was used automatically, it was definitively in the classpath. I added a Ribbon property for my route, could it have triggered it?

Comment: It's only used for routes with service ids, not the ones with urls.