# Zuul Hystrix stream without using serviceId

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, hystrix

I have a few Zuul routes defined and everything works great. The hystrix stream is empty and [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490269/spring-cloud-zuul-monitor-circuitbreaker-all-routes-via-hystrix) the reason is that I am not using a service.

So I would like some help on how I could work around this. I do not have Eureka (and do not wish to start using for this simple app). Is there some way to get the hystrix stream with url instead of serviceId?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Here are example routes I have configured. The URL placeholders come from my profile specific configs.

```
zuul.routes.v1stores.path=/v1/stores
zuul.routes.v1stores.url=${target.url}

zuul.routes.v1order.path=/v1/order/**
zuul.routes.v1order.url=${target.url}/v1/order
```

Comment: any codes pasted?

Comment: Your Zuul configuration would help.  If you are not using Eureka you can still have your routes wrapped in Hystrix Commands but you must use Ribbon.  See this section in our documentation which explains this http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR4/#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy

Comment: edited above to add route example. I have gone through that doc. The link in my original post clearly says that Ribbon is not used if using URL so I am trying to determine if I can get hystrix stream without using service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently using the `url` attribute, sets up zuul to NOT use Hystrix. You need to use ribbon to access the Hystrix functionality in Zuul. To do so, you could do something like this ([see docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR4/#_customizing_the_ribbon_client_using_properties)):

```
zuul.routes.v1order.path=/v1/order/**
zuul.routes.v1order.serviceId=v1order

v1order.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName=com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
v1order.ribbon.listOfServers=${target.url}
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer! That does the trick. One side effect I see is that content-encoding gzip gets added so I had a response body logger that now does not work. Maybe in a debug profile I can disable that somehow? Is there some config to disable gzip (was not able to find a ribbon prop)?

Comment: Thanks, Spencer. I was stumbling across a solution for this. But it took a while to figure this out.